# Best way to "restart" Akka after code change to a Scala file?

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I'm working with learning Scala and Spray to serve up an API, and each time I make a change to my Scala code, I have to restart the Akka server (currently just breaking out and then doing a `container:start`). Am I doing this wrong?

Coming from a scripting language I'm used to seeing my changes reflected instantly--but since this is compiled I guess this is a fact of life?

Comment: not exactly, you may use [jrebel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRebel)

Comment: That looks like it will do the trick. If you post an answer with this, i'll accept it

Comment: Please let us know if JRebel ends up working for your scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a long time there were no such way but now we have [JRebel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRebel) and I think it  is what you're looking for. There is already plugins ([revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver) and auxiliary [jrebel-plugin](https://github.com/Gekkio/sbt-jrebel-plugin)) for SBT but generally, JRebel is tool agnostic. Licenses are free for scala developers.